# Why do my in-line styles work, but my stylesheet isn't changing the code at all?

Tags: css, react-native

I am coding a navbar in React Native. Think of it as double layered -- the upper layer is a burger menu, a title, and a search icon, the second layer consists of three touchable titles to navigate to the relevant screens.

[a mock-up of the navbar I'm trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmOt1.png)

When I apply inline styles, they work. When I do Stylesheet.create and apply styles down there, they don't. I am new to programming and very confused.

My plan is to code a single navbar that is split into two rows (views): navbarTop and navbarBottom. I would very much appreciate some insight into whether doing so makes sense, and also how to fix my styling issue. Thank you all very much!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.navbarTop}>
        <View>
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => { 
              this.props.navigation.openDrawer();
            }}
          >
            <Image
              style={{marginBottom: 5}}
              source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/menu.png')}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: 'white',
              fontSize: 20,
              marginRight: 70
            }}
          >
            Dashboard
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Image
            style={{marginBottom: 5}}
            source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/search.png')}
          />  
        </View>

        <View style={styles.navbarBottom}>
          <View>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: 15,
                marginRight: 70
              }}
            > RECORDINGS </Text>
          </View>

          <View>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: 15,
                marginRight: 70
              }}
            > PATIENTS </Text>
          </View>

          <View>
            <Text
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: 15,
                marginRight: 70
              }}
            > DEVICES </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Navbar);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navbarTop: {
    backgroundColor: '#14172B',
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  // navbarBottom: {

  // }
});
```

Comment: Hi @dereknahman, In CSS inline styles have high priority than internal and external CSS. Thatswhy your inline CSS only work here. Try to check that other CSS makes an effect on your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In line styles over write the style which are present in the stylesheet.

Let's say there is a style component :

```
<View style = {[styles.demoView,{marginTop:50}]}/>


export default StyleSheet.create({
  demoView: {
    marginTop:20,
    flexDirection: "row",
    padding: "10rem",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
```

In the above style the inline style will replace the value of `marginTop` because it has high priority and the it would least concern even if you remove the `marginTop` property from the stylesheet as it is been supressed by inline style. Hope it gives you clear vision.
Happy Coding :)

Edit :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.navbarTop}>
          <TouchableHighlight 
            onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}}>
            <Image style={{marginBottom: 5}}
            source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/menu.png')}
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold',color: 'white',fontSize: 20,marginRight: 70}}>
            Dashboard
          </Text>

          <Image
            style={{marginBottom: 5}}
            source={require('./../../../android/app/src/main/res/drawable/search.png')}
          />  

        <View style={styles.navbarBottom}>
            <Text style={styles.navBarText}> RECORDINGS </Text>
<Text style={styles.navBarText}> PATIENTS </Text>
<Text style={styles.navBarText}> DEVICES </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(Navbar);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  navbarTop: {
    backgroundColor: '#14172B',
    padding: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  // navbarBottom: {

  // }
  navBarText:{
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 15,
      marginRight: 70
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any tips for making my app listen to StyleSheet.create rather that inline styles only?

Comment: The answer is already in my posted answer. If styles are inline then that particular value wont be called from stylesheet rather it would be taken from inline styles as they have high priority.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept that so other facing same doubt can have a clearer vision

Comment: But the styles from StyleSheet.create don't affect the appearance of my app even when the inline styles are completely removed, so inline styles taking precedence over StyleSheet.create doesn't seem to be the issue in this case

Comment: You might be doing something wrong. Share the complete code.